# Converting Obj-C print statement to Swift's native "\variable name" syntax

Tags: swift

I want to convert these two Obj-C statements to Swift. I'm not sure about the syntax since there are multiple object percent signs. I have converted most of the code except for the print strings with percent signs.

I want to use Swift's native print ("\variable") syntax.

> self.validFrames.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Valid Frames: %d%%", MIN(100, (100 * self.validFrameCounter)/MIN_FRAMES_FOR_FILTER_TO_SETTLE)];

`validFrames.text = String.localizedStringWithFormat("Valid Frames: \min%%"(100, (100 * validFrameCounter) / minFramesForFilterToSettle))`

> self.rate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", beat];

`rate.text = String.localizedStringWithFormat("\beat 0.0f")`

Please correct my Swift syntax.

Comment: This question is quite unclear.  What exactly are you trying to do (in plain English)?  What's your question, exactly?

Comment: question edited. trying to covert print statements

Comment: You still haven't explained in plain-English what you're trying to do.  What's the expected output of the strings supposed to look like?  What output are you getting and how does that differ from what you want, specifically?  Or are you getting errors preventing you from compiling?  What are those errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The interpolation syntax is `\(expression)`:

   ```
   let validFramesPercentage = MIN(100, (100 * self.validFrameCounter)/MIN_FRAMES_FOR_FILTER_TO_SETTLE)
   self.validFrames.text = "Valid Frames: \(validFramesPercentage)%"
   ```
2. You don't have any control over how Swift formats a float if you use interpolation syntax. Example:

   ```
   let beat = Float(10.0/3)
   self.rate.text = "\(beat)"
   // text is 3.33333; you can't specify the number of digits
   ```
3. If you want to use localized strings, you can't use `\(...)` interpolation. To perform interpolation, the compiler has to examine the string. Localized strings are loaded from a data file at runtime. The compiler doesn't look at them.
4. Using format strings in Swift is 100% ok. They are part of the library, just like `UIView` (or `NSView`).

Comment: Ok so I have already converted it all but kept the Obj-C print expressions as they are like this: `validFrames.text = String.localizedStringWithFormat("Valid Frames: %d%%", min(100, (100 * validFrameCounter) / minFramesForFilterToSettle))`
and 

`rate.text = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%0.0f", beat)`
. Are you saying this is ok?

Comment: Thanks Rob. Btw, How would you personally do it? Leave it as is?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you cannot achieve the result you want using *interpolation sintax*.

You should use for `Float`:

```
var text = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%0.0f", 2.0) // result: 2
```

And for `Int`:

```
var text = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%d%%", 10) // result 10%
```

Comment: Sorry, edited my question. I believe it's clearer now. I want to convert 2 Obj-C statements to Swift using Swift's native ("\name") syntax.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible using interpolation syntax. The way I suggested is correct, since the Swift class `String` has the method `localizedStringWithFormat`, allowing to control decimal places, etc, as you want to accomplish.